# Append text to existing Gzip file

Tags: c#, gzip, gzipstream

I'm working on a log program, which would dump data into gzip archive.

The first entry would look like this:

```
using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(logFile))
{
    using (var gs = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(gs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(logEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want add other lines to that file without having to re-read all file content and than to re-write it in a way that the result can be read with a single GZipStream.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: If you want to append something to a gzip/deflate stream, then you have to perform a Partial Flush or a Full Flush at the end each time. See [Zlib Flush Modes](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/deflate-flush.html). The GZipStream class does not support these flush modes. Solution: do not append or do not use the GZipStream class.

Comment: what library do you suggest instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gzlog.h`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [`gzlog.c`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c) from the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) distribution in the [examples](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/examples) directory.  They do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: any chance that this was translated into c#?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I would be easy to do.  Also there are .NET interfaces for zlib.  See http://zlib.net .